# How to fix echo variable inside html attribute?

Tags: php

I have a parse error unexpected = here specifically at action=.

```
<form action='<?php echo $url?resendpassword=1&send=1;?>' method='post'>
```

Comment: wrap in quotes <form action='<?php echo "$url?resendpassword=1&send=1";?>' method='post'>

Answer (score 1):

Try writing it like this;

```
<form action='<?php echo $url . "?resendpassword=1&send=1"; ?>' method='post'>
```

Or

```
<form action='<?php echo $url;?>?resendpassword=1&send=1' method='post'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other suggestions here are fine, but I think this may be even better:

```
<form action='<?php echo $url ?>?resendpassword=1&send=1;' method='post'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate URL first and then don't forget to escape (& is special character in HTML so without escaping it would produce incorrect HTML):

```
<form action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars("$url?resendpassword=1&send=1"); ?>' method='post'>
```